# Check an available time in between start and end time when given with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the below logic written to identify an available slot to initiate a meeting request in a system i am developing using yii framework.

```
// checks for availabilty of teacher
public function isTeacherAvailable($subjectId, $startAt, $endAt) {
    $success = true;
    $meetings = Meeting::model()->findAll("subjectId=:subjectId AND endAt>=:endAt AND type=:type", array(':subjectId' => $subjectId, ':endAt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), ':type' => '0')); // get all the meetings for subject that is not ended and active.
    foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
        if (($startAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($startAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        } else if (($endAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($endAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        }
    }
    return $success;
}
```

**This is an example of an input. StartAt: 2014-02-10 08:45:00 endAt: 2014-02-10 08:49:00.. you can skip the subjectId**

with this i am able to prevent creating meeting requests when already there is a meeting scheduled for a given StartAt and endAt.

one issue i am having is, it fails when i insert something like this.

**StartAt: 2014-02-10 08:40:00 endAt: 2014-02-10 08:55:00** (new request is outside the existing slots)

so the idea is when there is a meeting scheduled from **8 am to 9 am**. it should not allow creating a meeting from **7 am to 10** am like it stops for **7.30 am to 8.30** am and **8.30 am to 9.00 am**.

let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re wrote the function as following to achieve the solution.

```
// checks for availabilty of teacher
public function isTeacherAvailable($subjectId, $startAt, $endAt) {
    $success = true;
    $meetings = Meeting::model()->findAll("subjectId=:subjectId AND endAt>=:endAt AND type=:type", array(':subjectId' => $subjectId, ':endAt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), ':type' => '0')); // get all the meetings for subject that is not ended and active.
    foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
        if (($startAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($startAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        } else if (($endAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($endAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        } else if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startAt)) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($meeting->startAt)) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endAt)) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($meeting->endAt))) { //if same date
            if ($startAt <= $meeting->startAt && $endAt >= $meeting->endAt) {
                $success = false; // trying to create outside a existing slot when there is one in middle on same day.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the two conditions being evaluated exclusively:

```
    if CONDITION1 then FALSE else if CONDITION2 then FALSE
```

The two conditions should be tested in OR:

```
    if CONDITION1 or CONDITION2 then FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// checks for availabilty of teacher
public function isTeacherAvailable($subjectId, $startAt, $endAt) {
    $success = true;
    $meetings = Meeting::model()->findAll("subjectId=:subjectId AND endAt>=:endAt AND type=:type", array(':subjectId' => $subjectId, ':endAt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), ':type' => '0')); // get all the meetings for subject that is not ended and active.
    foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
        if (($startAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($startAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        } else if (($endAt >= $meeting->startAt) && ($endAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        } else if (($startAt <= $meeting->startAt && $endAt >= $meeting->startAt) || ($startAt >= $meeting->startAt && $startAt <= $meeting->endAt)) {
            $success = false; // trying to create inside a existing slot.
            break;
        }
    }
    return $success;
}
```